# Passing Session parameters to Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

I wanted to do two tasks simultaneously in web project in the Servlet once the user clicks on submit button 
1. Run a code to trigger some backend activity 
2. Display a webpage to the user. 
I tried with the code sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191029/running-two-independent-tasks-simultaneously-using-threads)

As I have few session attributes being set I need to set this in one of the thread. I tried putting point one in one thread and point two in second but variables are not getting resolved to the thread from doPost() method.

Servlet:

```
public class JOBRUN extends HttpServlet{
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse     response) throws ServletException, IOException {
     AESASNewOpenPeriod=request.getParameter("AESASNewOpenPeriod");
     ScriptRunOption = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("AESASJOBRUNOPTION"));
     HttpSession session=request.getSession();
     String Stream="aaaa";
     session.setAttribute("AEStream", Stream);
     //Do Job 1 (Update table)
     //Do Job 2 (Display webpage to user)
        }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);

}
```

Comment: Can you show code: what you have tried?

Comment: You don't need to pass session parameters to a thread. The thread can get them for itself. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @a3.14_Infinity: Updated with servlet code

Comment: @EJP: Referring to above code I want to execute "Job 1" and "Job 2" simultaneously.

Comment: You want to do these tasks within the scope of request? i.e, you want it as blocking- meaning only after completing 2 tasks, response should be sent back?

Comment: @TomSebastian: No, just after triggering "Job 1" I want the webpage to be displayed to user I mean "Job 2", Job2 need not wait till Job1 completes

Answer (score 1):

You can create an anonymous thread (if you don't want a dedicated `Thread` class for ) Job 1.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    Session localSession = session;// assign the session object to thread variable.
    public void run() {
        // you can access localSession here. and do the JOB 1
    }
}).start();// this will run asynchrously(non blocking).
```

Also if you want to pass only some attributes to do the Job 1(i,e if u don't want to change the session), you can pass relevant attributes only.For example

```
String threadStream = session.setAttribute("AEStream");//local memeber variable  inside anonymous thread
```

Then from the next line after thread, you can do Job 2.

*Note: If you mean something else- running an asychrounous worker thread with request , you start wit Servlet 3.x [AsyncContext](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/AsyncContext.html)*