# Divide all the files present in the directory/folder to different thread for faster execution

Tags: java, multithreading

I got a program in which I have to write two thread that will perform same operation on the files present in a particular folder. That operation is to read all the files in that folder and then delete all of them present there. These two thread will have same operation but just to increase the process time I have to divide the files between two thread so that execution time is saved. I tried this way but it is not dividing the no. of files between threads but takes all the files and do the operation and if the file is deleted by one thread then other thread should not pick that file up. The code I wrote is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    service.submit(new thread1());
    service.submit(new thread2());

    service.shutdown();
    service.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);

    System.exit(0);
}

public static class thread1 implements Callable<Object> {

    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        t1();
        return null;
    }
}

public static class thread2 implements Callable<Object> {

    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        t1();
        return null;

    }
}

public static void t1() {

    Path myDir = Paths.get("D:/Astha/");
    File file = new File("D:/Astha/");
    boolean running = true;
    while (running) {
        try {
            WatchService watcher = myDir.getFileSystem().newWatchService();
            myDir.register(watcher, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);

            WatchKey watckKey = watcher.take();

            List<WatchEvent<?>> events = watckKey.pollEvents();
            for (@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            WatchEvent event : events) {
                if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE) {
                    System.out.println("Created: " + event.context().toString() + "By "
                            + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }
            }
            if (file.exists()) {
                File[] files = file.listFiles();
                for (File f : files) {
                    if (f.delete()) {
                        System.out.println("Deleting the file: " + f.getName() + "By "
                                + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    }
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("No files in the folder");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

In this above program, I also need to apply lock on one thread so that no other thread can perform operation on that. How do I implement lock here?

Comment: You have a number of choices, you could place all the files into some kind of blocking queue and simply pop off the next file to be processed as the thread(s) become available.  Another solution would be to use a `ExecutorService` of some kind (probably a limited pooled service) and simply add a new "task" for each file to it and simply let it deal with it

Comment: I am not very much familiar with blocking queue and executor service.

Comment: Here's a good opportunity to get started and learn something new :)

Comment: [`ExecutorService` example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191029/running-two-independent-tasks-simultaneously-using-threads/12191090#12191090)

Comment: How to implement that way?

Comment: Take a look at the example, run it, see how it works, adapt it a little, see what changes the impact has, expand and adapt it to your needs, be happy, [read the Executors trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html), expand and discover

Comment: Be aware that for an I/O bound process like this adding a thread may make it run _slower_, because you'll be asking the disk to jump back and forth more.  Seek time is the largest component of disk latency, unless your disk is an SSD.

Comment: @MadProgrammer How do I synchronize these two threads?

Comment: @AsthaSrivastava In my examples, you don't, they take care of themselves. For your needs, you don't need to, you'd create a task for each file which the executor service will manage for you

Comment: @MadProgrammer See above result of the program. It is creating only one thread. Why is that so? Is anything missing there?

Comment: You only add a single task

Comment: @MadProgrammer Now it is working fine but I need to implement lock synchronization also. How to implement it here? I tried doing it in t1() method but that is not giving desired output.

Comment: @AsthaSrivastava Why do you need a lock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your (updated) code, you have two basic task.  You have a "watch" task and you have a "process" task

## `WatcherService`

The `WatcherService` basically takes a `Path` and a `ExecutorService`, it monitors the given path and creates new `FileTask` tasks

```
public class WatcherService implements Callable<Object> {

    private Path path;
    private ExecutorService service;

    public WatcherService(Path path, ExecutorService service) {
        this.path = path;
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        do {
            try {
                WatchService watcher = path.getFileSystem().newWatchService();
                path.register(watcher, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);

                WatchKey watckKey = watcher.take();

                List<WatchEvent<?>> events = watckKey.pollEvents();
                for (@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") WatchEvent event : events) {
                    WatchEvent<Path> we = (WatchEvent<Path>)event;
                    service.submit(new FileTask(we.context()));
                }
            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
        } while (true && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
        return null;
    }

}
```

## `FileTask`

The `FileTask` takes a `Path` and performs some operation upon it

```
public class FileTask implements Callable<Object> {

    private Path path;

    public FileTask(Path file) {
        this.path = file;
    }

    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        File file = path.toFile();
        if (file.exists()) {
            if (file.delete()) {
                //...
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

## Hooking it up

Basically, you create a `ExecutorService` and `submit` a `WatcherService` and let it run...

```
Path path = Paths.get("D:/Astha/");
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
service.submit(new WatcherService(path, service));
```

This creates a pooled service of three threads, one for the watcher and two for the `FileTask`s

You may find that this still does not offer you any benefit, as the disk I/O won't allow multiple operations to carried out in parallel and will block until the first operation completes before the next can be carried out

Answer (score 1):

You could put all Files to edit in a HashSet or Map.

`private static volatile Set<String> filenames;`

If one of your threads is able to get the next File, use a synchronized Method to deliver it.

```
public synchronized String getNextMessage() {
if(filenames.size()<1) {
  return null;
} else {
  final String result = filenames.get(0);
  filenames.remove(0);
  return result;
}
```

Instead of a String, you could also use File, URI or Path, depending on your needs.

Comment: Or use a [`BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) of some kind which would basically do the same thing for you